# Evaluate Cubic sum of consecutive numbers to infinity

Tags: number-theory, summation

I am trying to evaluate the following sum to infinity $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^3}{4^i}$. Here's how i tried it but i am stuck, any help is greatly appreciated.
$$S = \frac{0^3}{0^3} + \frac{1^3}{4^1} + \frac{2^3}{4^2} + \frac{3^3}{4^3} + \frac{4^3}{4^4} {...}\infty 
 (1)$$
$$4S = \frac{0^3}{0^3} + 1^3 + \frac{2^3}{4^1} + \frac{3^3}{4^2} + \frac{4^3}{4^3} {...}\infty  (2
)$$

$$Subtracting (1) from (2) $$
$$3S  = 1^3 + \frac{7}{4^1} + \frac{19}{4^2} + \frac{37}{4^3} {...}\infty  (3
)$$

I was able to evaluate the sums for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^i} = \frac{4}{3}$ , $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i}{4^i} = \frac{4}{9}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^2}{4^i} = \frac{20}{27}$ using above approach, but i am not able to see any patterns in the (3) summation above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)= \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ for all $|x|<1$

Now differentiate $f$ to get that $f' = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}$ and so $ x f' = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n}$, differentiate a second time to get that $ (x f')' =  \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n-1}$ and so $ x (x f')' =  \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^{n}$, differentiate a third time to get that $  (x (x f')')' =  \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 x^{n-1}$ and so  $ x (x (x f')')' =  \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 x^{n}$ with the fact that $f =\frac{1}{1-x}$ we get that $ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3 x^{n} = \frac{x(1+4x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4} $ substituting $x=1/4$ we get that $ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{4^n} = \frac{44}{27}$

With this method you can find closed form for any sum of the form $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k x^n$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, granted this method will get very ugly very quickly

Comment: Thanks a ton for another solution using calculus.

Answer (score 1):

$$3S  = 1^3 + \frac{7}{4^1} + \frac{19}{4^2} + \frac{37}{4^3} {...}=
  $$
$$  = 1^3 + \frac{2^3-1^3}{4^1} + \frac{3^3-2^3}{4^2} + \frac{4^3-3^3}{4^3} {...}= $$

$$\sum _{i=0}^\infty \frac {(i+1)^3-i^3}{4^i}=\sum _{i=0}^\infty \frac {3i^2+3i}{4^i}$$

You can take over from here.

Comment: Thanks. Now its solvable. I couldn't see that pattern earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.